# Чи дійсно варто замінювати "через" на "за"?

Tags: правопис

[OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BA/)

> Замініть конструкцію через рік на стилістично кращий варіант: за рік.

[image]

Чи дійсно варто замінювати "через" на "за"? Яке правило пояснює дану заміну?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Варто замінити.

Прийменник "Через" часто-густо має значення "з якоїсь причини". Наприклад **ми не купуємо автівку через економію**. Звісно це не єдине значення цього прийменника, як справедливо зазначено в коментарях.

http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-za-krok-odynadtsyatyj/ - тут є є багато правил вживання прийменника за, зокрема:

> Вживання прийменника ЗА є нормативним у тих випадках, коли вживається:
>
> 1) з Родовим відмінком у значенні часу:
>
> за часів Римської імперії, за керівництва Петренка;
>
> АЛЕ неправильно:
>
> за часів дитинства, юності – в дитинстві, в юності!!!

Read more: http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-za-krok-odynadtsyatyj/#ixzz5UIoSXuNs

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті і сподіваємось на плідну співпрацю.

Comment: Але ж слово _[через](http://sum.in.ua/s/cherez)_ має **не лише** значення причини (зокрема значення 6 за наведеним мною посиланням якраз стосується поставленого питання й підтверджене цитатами Шевченка, Квітки-Основ'яненка, Тютюнника, Гончара, Стельмаха).